# zookeeper + Kafka - Unable to create data directory

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I´m using zookeeper 3.4.8 in single node and try to use kafka.

When I run this command:

```
zookeeper-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.2    /config/zookeeper.properties
```

I get the below error:

```
[2016-02-22 17:32:41,661] ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.io.IOException: Unable to create data directory /var/zookeeper/version-2
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.<init>(FileTxnSnapLog.java:85)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:104)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:86)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:52)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem.  Can you perform the command if you sudo it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One reason could be the inappropriate path specified to zoo.config file.
A lot of solutions on the web specifies the path as ":\zookeeper-3.4.7\data".

Instead of the above mentioned format, specify the address as full path from your C: drive to the data folder. It worked for me. (Don't forget to put double slash \ instead of one in case you're on windows)

Comment: This was exactly the case and it was fixed. Sharing my correct data dir: "dataDir= C:\\Program Files\Apache Zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.11\data"

Answer (score 8):

I got this problem for this setting on Windows PC:

```
dataDir=c:/data/zoo/
```

and thus this error:

```
2016-12-02 15:29:25,327 [myid:] - ERROR [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@64] - Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally
java.io.IOException: Unable to create data directory ??:\data\zoo\version-2
```

Problem was solved by changing (I have ZooKeeper on C disk unpackaged)

```
dataDir=/data/zoo/
```

Also run command line tool as Administrator if needed

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, and this works with

> sudo bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't have permission to write to the directory `log.dirs` (see zookeeper.properties). Change the directory to a different one, change the permission setting of the current `log.dirs` directory or run Kafka as different user. You can use the command `ls -l /var/zookeeper` to see the current permissions and then `chmod` to change the permissions.

Comment: I'm glad that it works but I'd recommend to change the folder permissions instead of running Zookeeper as sudo.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that zookeeper has no permission. Trying to use the administrator role to install it.

Answer (score 1):

For window's machine

Solved : Use double slashes inside the path while defining the dataDir path

dataDir=E:\\tools\\zookeeperdata\\data

Answer (score 0):

And in my windows 10 system, using zookeeper 3.4.10. the `dataDir` attribute should setting like `:\\\\zookeeper\\\\data`, not `d:\zookeeper\data`. it also can setting as linux file system separator(`d:/zookeeper/data`). then this problem should be ok. And in linux, I think it permission problem. also it can come across when dataDir is under driver C in windows system.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the zookeeper in the Windows 10 machine we need to specify the dataDir property something like this

"dataDir=C:\zookeeper-3.4.13\data"

Answer (score 0):

In my windows 10 system, using zookeeper 3.4.13, the following example path is working:

"dataDir=C:\\dev\\tools\\zookeeper-3.4.13\\data"

You have to use double backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

on `zoo.cfg` you need to change directory to above or anything similar:

```
dataDir=C:/zookeeper-3.4.14/zookeeper-3.4.14/data
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows, set dataDir to full path where you have no access restrictions - with no quotes("")

```
dataDir=C:\\your-path\
dataDir=C:\\zk\tmp\
```

Note: I have observed the command to fail for some of the path(though full access) and running command prompt as administrator has solved it.

Answer (score -1):

For windows the below too works:

```
dataDir=C:\\zookeeper-3.4.14\\zookeeper-3.4.14\\data
```