# zookeeper - [NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856

Tags: apache-zookeeper, java-11

I am trying to insttall zookeeper in my Windows. I am getting the error bellow no matter which suggestion I followed in [zookeeper + Kafka - Unable to create data directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561723/zookeeper-kafka-unable-to-create-data-directory).

I am running it as Administrator and I have tried all these options:

```
#dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
#dataDir=:\zookeeper-3.4.14\
#dataDir=C:\\_d\\WSs\\kafka\\zookeeper-3.4.14\\data
#dataDir=:\\\\zookeeper\\\\data
dataDir=C:\\_d\\WSs\\kafka\\zookeeper-3.4.14
```

I don´t think it is relevant but let me add here: I have Java 11.

Any idea why it is happening will be appreciated.

Full logs

```
C:\Windows\system32>zkserver

C:\Windows\system32>call "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"\bin\java "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\.." "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE" -cp "C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\build\classes;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\build\lib\*;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\*;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\*;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf" org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg"
2019-04-18 15:17:42,629 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg
2019-04-18 15:17:42,644 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
2019-04-18 15:17:42,644 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
2019-04-18 15:17:42,644 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
2019-04-18 15:17:42,644 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@116] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2019-04-18 15:17:42,769 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg
2019-04-18 15:17:42,769 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@98] - Starting server
2019-04-18 15:17:47,344 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.14-4c25d480e66aadd371de8bd2fd8da255ac140bcf, built on 03/06/2019 16:18 GMT
2019-04-18 15:17:47,344 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:host.name=DESKTOP-AKCNE7F
2019-04-18 15:17:47,344 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.version=11.0.2
2019-04-18 15:17:47,344 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2019-04-18 15:17:47,344 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
2019-04-18 15:17:47,344 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.class.path=C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\build\classes;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\build\lib\*;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\zookeeper-3.4.14.jar;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\jline-0.9.94.jar;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\netty-3.10.6.Final.jar;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf
2019-04-18 15:17:47,344 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\_d\tools\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\_d\WSs\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\;C:\Users\jimis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\jimis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\jimis\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.
2019-04-18 15:17:47,360 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\jimis\AppData\Local\Temp\
2019-04-18 15:17:47,360 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2019-04-18 15:17:47,360 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Windows 10
2019-04-18 15:17:47,360 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2019-04-18 15:17:47,376 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=10.0
2019-04-18 15:17:47,376 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=jimis
2019-04-18 15:17:47,376 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=C:\Users\jimis
2019-04-18 15:17:47,376 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=C:\Windows\system32
2019-04-18 15:17:47,391 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@836] - tickTime set to 2000
2019-04-18 15:17:47,391 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@845] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
2019-04-18 15:17:47,391 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@854] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
2019-04-18 15:17:47,782 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ServerCnxnFactory@117] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory
2019-04-18 15:17:47,797 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2019-04-18 15:18:00,365 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@222] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:54057
2019-04-18 15:18:00,375 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@222] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:54058
2019-04-18 15:18:00,378 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856
2019-04-18 15:18:00,379 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1056] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:54057 (no session established for client)
```

*** Edited

[image]

*** edited

[image]

*** The answer to my question is "you can ignore the fact that I get an error while curl 127.0.0.1:port. Kafka is working anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you trying to do a "HTTP GET" against the zookeeper client port?

So the error comes from [NIOServerCnxn.java:readLength](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/NIOServerCnxn.java#L535) which is expecting either a 4-letter command or buffer where the first 4 bytes represent size.

The number 1195725856 in hex is 0x47455420 which is "GET " in ASCII.

So the error message is caused when you try to do a HTTP GET" against the 2181 port.

```
$ curl http://0.0.0.0:2181/
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
$ sudo tail /var/log/zookeeper/zookeeper.out
...
2019-04-19 12:56:25,303 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted 
2019-04-19 12:56:25,304 [myid:3] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856
2019-04-19 12:56:25,304 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:33011 (no session established for client)
```

This `WARN` message is safe to ignore since ZooKeeper will just close that client session which is implied by the `curl` response.

Comment: I checked throw netstat -anp | find ":"2181" and I can see the port is free. I added the logs in my original question above. Are you aware about any possible conflict with Hiperr-V? I have a lap top provided by my company and I can't install Docker because there is some conflict with Citrix Receivere used and which I can't turn off. Well, I am mentioning my issue with Docker in case it can ring a bell in your mind about any possible issue with Zookeepr also. Does Zookeeper depends on some virtualization behind the scene?

Comment: I haven't used Docker or the Citrix software so I can't help in regards to that.  ZooKeeper is just a multi-threaded Java application.  No virtualization that I'm aware  of.

Comment: well, since you reproduced my issue, what do you suggest I am check around? PS. the port numberr is free

Comment: The errror does not mean that ZooKeeper is not working.  It just says the wrong command was attempted.  Try `echo stat | nc 127.0.0.1 2181` on you host to see if your ZooKeeper is working.

Comment: I added a print screen which shows two cmd windows: 1 - I started Zookeeper and 
 (2) another I pinged it via netcat. Does it mean something usefull to you? Honestly all I want is install Kafka.Do you know if I can ignore the fact that I can get it via curl and go forward?

Comment: Your `stat` shows ZooKeeper is working so I'm pretty sure you can ignore it.  I probably wasn't clear enough if my answer.

Comment: You are 100% right. I started Kafka and I did a simple test and it is working. I will add it here for future readers.